Pugh Analysis Integral Question
This is Exercise 39 of Chapter 4, Real Mathematical Analysis by Pugh.
Let f : [0, 2π] → R be a continuous function such that for all natural n=1,2,3,...
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) \sin (n x) d x=0
$$
Then show that f is constant.
I know that for all natural n
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi}\sin (n x) d x=0
$$
but have no idea how to proceed.Thanks in advance.

n is natural number

I'm not sure that the statement is correct, try with $f(x)=\sin(x/2)$

that is right.I edited the question.

Consider, $f(x) = \cos x$

@user317176 is that a counterexample ?

Yes, with $m,n \in \mathbb N, \int_0^{2\pi} \cos mx\sin nx\ dx = 0$

But f should be fixed.Is it true that for all natural n $$
\int_0^{2 \pi} cos(x) \sin (n x) d x=0
$$

$\cos x=\cos (1\cdot x)$

that makes sense

could you give a sketch of how to prove that result ?

Hint: $\sin a \cos b=\frac12(\sin (a+b)+\sin(a-b))$
